# How does one use and express a differential operators in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations, polynomials

I am trying to understand sympy and having trouble expressing and/or using various Rodrigues-type formulas. Examples of what I am trying to express:

```
# x - variable
# n - integer
# H - Hermite polynomials
# E - exponential function "e**x"
# D - differential operator of x

assert H(n,x) == (-1)**n*E(x**2)*D**n*E(-x**2)
assert H(n,x) == (E(-D**2)*x**n)(2*x)
```

In general, this would appear to be an overall issue is expressing differential operators and/or linear operators on polynomials. How does one create an infinite order differential operator in sympy? How does one compare operators? Is there a notation of operator simplification? For example, in general, we know

```
assert E(t*D)*f(x) == f(x+t)
```

Does sympy have the ability to express and simplify this differential operator to a linear shift operator? Or at the least, to know that they are equal?

Comment: There isn't a differential operator of the type that you are looking for in sympy (although it could be added). It is possible that sympy can already do what you want in a different way but for a more extended discussion I suggest using the sympy mailing list.

Comment: lol, you followed me to stackoverflow. Thanks for the suggestion. I thought I should try here before bothering the distro.